# Supply target path to shortcut that includes both the program and a file via Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, shortcuts

I'm attempting to create a script that creates a shortcut with admin privileges for every Powershell script in a given directory, what I have so far:

```
$scripts = Get-ChildItem -path "C:\Users\djcim\Google Drive\Powershell Scripts\*.ps1" -Recurse
foreach ($script in $scripts) {
    $shortcutFile = [io.path]::ChangeExtension($script.FullName, '.lnk')
    $WScriptShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
    $Shortcut = $WScriptShell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutFile)
    $Shortcut.TargetPath = "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
    $Shortcut.Save()

    $bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($ShortcutFile)
    $bytes[0x15] = $bytes[0x15] -bor 0x20
    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($ShortcutFile, $bytes)

    Move-Item -Path $shortcutFile -Destination "C:\Users\djcim\Google Drive\Powershell Scripts\Admin Shortcuts" -force
}
```

The above successfully creates a shortcut with admin privileges per script, however the target is only to Powershell and not the scripts themselves.

I really need the shorcut target to be Powershell -f [script path], example:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -f "C:\Users\GJBalaich\Google Drive\Powershell Scripts\FFmpeg\FFclip.ps1"
```

However when I try to set that as the target path via Powershell, examples:

```
$Shortcut.TargetPath = "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -f " + "`"" + $script + "`""
$Shortcut.TargetPath = "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -f " + $script
```

it throws the error "Value does not fall within the expected range."

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass arguments to the target, do this:

```
'Set the additional parameters for the shortcut  
$Shortcut.Arguments = "C:\Users\GJBalaich\Google Drive\Powershell Scripts\FFmpeg\FFclip.ps1"
```